# How do I test whether non-zero numbers in a long datastream are clumped more than chance?

Tags: statistics

I have a long string of integers between 0 and 9. Most of them are 0, but some are not. I want to know if the non-zero ones "clump" together - if their distribution is such that it is statistically more likely than chance that non-0 numbers will be found adjacent to each other. What's the right statistical test to check this?

Comment: A runs test for values above and below 1/2.

Comment: Apologies for posting my comments as an "Answer" before - the web page was not letting me Comment on my own posting (account screwup).  I'm not familiar with Minitab but I will take a look.    If anyone knows of an easy way to do it in Excel, please let me know.

Comment: Google 'runs test in Excel'. Or better yet, read about the runs test. For a long string, you can use a normal approximation, and use software only for counting the runs (which can get tedious). The point (not made really clear in my answer) was not to have you use Minitab, but to give you search words 'runs test' and a clue what to look for.

Comment: Understood. I'm reading about it now, but will this kind of test just tell me if the *number* of non-zero values is abnormal or not, or will it also analyze their *distribution* (test a hypothesis of clumping more often than chance)?  thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right answer. The more I read about the RUNS test the more it seems like it will test the property of randomness; I already know my data stream is definitely not random overall (way more 0's than if the numbers had an equal chance of appearing in each place). What I need to know is whether the distribution of non-0 numbers is clumped or what would be expected by a random placement. Ran the RUNS test tell me that?

Comment: You confuse randomness with equal numbers of 0s and 1s. A die with 0s on five sides and 1 on one side can be randomly tossed. A grossly unfair coin heavily biased towards tails, can be tossed randomly. As you describe the problem, a runs test is just what you need to test randomness. (A different procedure would be used to find out, as you already know, that the proportion of 0s is greater than 1/2.)

Answer (score 0):

**About a runs test of randomness.**

Below I am pasting a short session in Minitab software. It is one statistical package that implements a runs test. I simulated 1000 observations from the
distribution $Binom(n = 0, p = .03)$ and put them into C1. This distribution has values from 0 through 9. With $p = .03,$ it has a higher probability of 0 than anything else. Use of the formula for this distribution suggests we should get around 760 0's in such a simulation. My simulation showed 759 0's (surprisingly close). (Minitab's expected number of runs is found from the formula in the NIST discussion of runs tests: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35d.htm )

It is not a surprise that my simulated sample passed the test for randomness because Minitab has a pretty good pseudorandom number generator. The actual number of runs found was very close to the expected number, so the P-value is quite large, indicating that my sample is consistent with randomness.
(A P-value less than about .05 would cast doubt on randomness.)

Of course, no statistical test is perfect. A sampling procedure can be imperfect, produce nonrandom data, and still 'pass' the runs test. Also, a truly random procedure can 'fail' the test (5% of the time).

```
MTB > random 1000 c1;
SUBC> binom 9, .03.
MTB > Runs .5 C1.

Runs Test: C1 

Runs test for C1

Runs above and below K = 0.5

The observed number of runs = 358
The expected number of runs = 366.838
241 observations above K, 759 below
P-value = 0.445
```

There are other tests for randomness, but I think the runs test is simplest
and well matched to your situation.

*Addendum:* Various postings made before I wrote this answer have been removed. Accordingly, I have made slight changes to make this Answer self-contained.